# JBoss JAAS custom Login Module

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, jaas

I'm trying to use a custom `JAAS` authentication module for a web based application hosted on `JBoss 5.1.0.GA`. So everything seems to be working fine, until the number of users increases and sessions (so it think) start getting mixed.

The reason i'm using the custom JAAS is because of a custom authentication backend and the need to pass back the password for futher usage in the application.

When i call request.getUserPrincipal in servlets i get an object of type SimplePrincipal instead on my custom principal. To get the user i'm using `SecurityAssociation.getSubject().getPrincipals()` and suspect that at this point i'm getting the incorrect principal.

Whats the correct way to implement a customing login module and retrieving the loggedin Principal on the web layer(Serlets) on JBoss?

**EDIT:**
The problem exists on the EJB layer, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-1756

Ref:

1. http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/05/16/writing-a-custom-jaas-loginmodule/
2. http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecurityJAASLoginModule
3. http://community.jboss.org/message/531986#531986
4. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/JAASLMDevGuide.html
5. http://community.jboss.org/thread/44388
6. http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/pdf/Security_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-5-Security_Guide-en-US.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the `LoginModule` with my custom principal working. I created a Tomcat [`valve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html) that encrypts and pushes the password to the [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). Other servlets will retrieve and decrypt the password.