# JBoss JAAS custom Login Module Error messages

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, jaas

I have an application that makes used of a [custom login module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692546/jboss-jaas-custom-login-module) of JBoss. Authentication can fail for a wide variety of reasons and i have to display these to the user instead of the usual `Inavlid username / password` error.

Is there a way to get error message from the login message? I think the best would be to through an exception since authenticate returns a boolean, however i can't figure how to catch it after authentication. Any pointers welcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used valve `org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.ExtendedFormAuthenticator` and grabbed `j_exception` from the session.

Ref:

1. http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2009/August/Form_Based_Login_with_JAAS_on_JBoss_and_ZK
2. http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExtendedFormAuthenticator

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Database login module and then get the exception using

Exception e =  (Exception) SecurityContextAssociation.getContextInfo("org.jboss.security.exception");

You can use this code inside managed bean function to fetch the error message ex.

```
public String getLoginFailureMsg(){
        Exception e =  (Exception) SecurityContextAssociation.
                                     getContextInfo("org.jboss.security.exception");
        if(e != null){
            if(e.getMessage().contains("PB00019"))
                return "invalid username";
            else
                return "invalid password";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

for setting up JAAS with Jboss 7 see this blow:

http://amatya.net/blog/implementing-security-with-jaas-in-jboss-as-7/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem..., but I don't like writting code tied to container for obvious reasons.

So what I did was to add the exception to the session myself.

First, build a ThreadLocal exception holder to send the exception between LoginContext and ServletContext:

```
public final class SecurityThreadLocal {
 private static final ThreadLocal<Exception> j_exception = new ThreadLocal<Exception>();

 public static void setException(Exception e) {
   j_exception.set(e);
 }

 public static Exception getException() {
   return (Exception)j_exception.get();
 }

 public static void clear() {
   j_exception.remove();
 }
```

}

Add LoginException to SecurityThreadLocal:

```
    catch (Exception e) { // or just catch LoginException
      log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
      SecurityThreadLocal.setException(e);
    }
```

Add Exception to the HttpSession with a Filter:

**web.xml**

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**SecurityFilter.java**

```
  if (uri.endsWith("<form-error-page>") && session != null){
    Exception j_exception = SecurityThreadLocal.getException();
    if( j_exception != null)
      session.setAttribute("j_exception", j_exception);
  }
```

But you should know as I know this is a bad practice and a security crack.

Well.., in my case the customer won ...